# Prove the bound $|f'(x)| \leq c |f(x)|$ for a submultiplicative function$f$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ be a submultiplicative function, i.e. $$f(x+y) \leq C f(x) f(y), \qquad x,y \in \mathbb{R},$$ for some $C>0$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable. Does there exist a constant $c>0$ such that $$|f'(x)|\leq c |f(x)|$$ for all $x$ sufficiently large?

**My thoughts:** If $C=1$ and $f(0)=1$, then this follows from the fact that

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq f(x) \frac{f(h)-1}{h} \to f(x) f'(0). \tag{1}$$

In general, however, we can either assume (without loss of generality) $C=1$ *or* $f(0)=1$, but not both, so we cannot use this argumentation. Moreover, we cannot expect $c=f'(0)$ (as in $(1)$); just take some submultiplicative function which is constant in a neighborhood of $0$ (e.g. a "smoothed" version of the function $f(x) = |x| \wedge 1$).

I tried several other estimates/approaches, but I always end up with the same problem - they work perfectly well if $C=1$ *and* $f(0)=1$, but the general case is much more difficult. (On the other hand, I cannot think of a submultiplicative function which does *not* satisfy the claim.)

Any ideas, counterexamples or references are welcome.

Comment: $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h \le \frac{f(x)(Cf(h)-1)}h$$
So we want $f(0) = \frac1C$.

Comment: You can use $f(0+0)=f(0)$

Comment: you can see that if $f(x)$ is a solution to $f(x+y) \le Cf(x)f(y)$ so is $e^{kx}f(x).$ suppose you had $|f'(x)| < c|f(x)|$ replacing $f$ by $fe^{kx}$ gives you $|f'(x)| < \frac{c}{k}$ and letting $k \to \infty$ gives $f(x) = 0$ for any $x.$

Comment: @AlexR It's not that easy - if we change $f$ in a neighborhood of $0$, then also the constant $C$ changes.

Comment: @saz I'm not suggesting that you change $f$ in any way. I only mean to say that if you can prove $f(0) = \frac1C$ from $f\in C^1(\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_{++})$ and $f(x+y) \le Cf(x)f(y)$, you are done.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i used the inequalities wrong.

Comment: @Abellan No problem; thank you for sharing your idea. :)

Comment: @AlexR I see; thanks for the clarification. I think that this approach fails - because this would yield a bound of the form $|f'(x)| \leq c |f'(0)|$. (In general, this estimate does not hold true; take a submultiplcative function which is constant in a neighborhood of $0$, then $f'(0)=0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is
$$
f(x) = e^x ( 2 + \sin x^2).
$$
From the inequalities $e^x \le f(x) \le 3e^x$, we see that $f$ is indeed submultiplicative:
$$
f(x+y) \le 3e^{x+y} \le 3e^xe^y \le 3f(x)f(y).
$$
However,
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{2 + \sin x^2 + 2x\cos x^2}{2 + \sin x^2},
$$
which equals $x+1$ for all $x$ of the form $\sqrt{2\pi k}$ and $-x+1$ for all $x$ of the form $\sqrt{2\pi k+\pi}$ ($k\in\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice counterexample. :)